# Using prevState in React while doing setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-deployment

can someone try to give me the answer about the topic. 
If i try to do the Interval the proper way (with cleanup and everything)

```
const [count,setCount] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = useInterval(() => setCount((count) => count + 1),1000);

  () => clearInterval(interval)
},[])
```

i know i can't put:

```
  const interval = useInterval(() => setCount(count + 1),1000);
```

i have to use `(count) => count + 1`, the previous value, but why is that? I can't put my head around it?

If my count is `count = 0` why does it always loop it to 1 if i don't use prevState...
Isn't state supposed to re-render the component when it's changed, even if i use `setCount(count + 1` so once it gets to 1 , re-renderes and then the state is 1 so interval can add +1 to it again.

Comment: This is a classic "stale closure", which rather than explain yet again I will allow you to google to find any number of excellent explanations that already exist. In short, even though the component rerenders with a new count, the setInterval handler is still hanging on to the original one with a value of 0.

Comment: Yeah, [MDN has a thorough explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Will look at the link you guys provided, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The function you pass to `useInterval` (or any closure defined in a render) will always "see" the state from the render it was defined in. When you call a state setter, the value does not change straight away as well, that happens on the next render that just got triggered. When you created that function, you (unknowingly, but this is just JS semantics) bound that function to the current value of count that happened to be there when the function was first defined. Somewhere in memory,

You might wonder why in other places you don't do this and it's fine, and it's probably because the setter is called within a function which was also recreated on the render so it avoids needing it technically (though you should always do it if it's derived from value to prevent gotchas). When this happens, that old function from the previous render is binned and replaced with the new one bound to the new scope.

But here, that effect is registered just once, which will be on the first time the component loads. Now `() => setCount(count + 1)` is lexically bound to the `count` value that was there on that initial render. That's `0`, so it evaluates to `0 + 1 = 1` every time. On the first render, somewhere deep in the browser memory `() => setCount(count + 1)` was stored and is hard wired to a static count value.

To get around this, React can accept the callback pattern you outlined. Internally in React, it passes to it the most up to date value so what render the function was defined in becomes irrelevant.